# Reusing of Beans

Tags: jsf, javabeans

On the Dashboard each User can see some Basic Stats. Lets take for example the "last login" Date. (But there are many more stats / values / settings to display)

The XHTML Files looks simplidfied like this:

```
<h:outputText value="statisticController.lastLoginDate()" />
```

The Bean itself uses `@Inject` to get the Session and therefore the current user:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public StatisticController{
    @Inject
    private mySessionBean mySession;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
       //load stats for mySession.currentUser;
    }
}
```

Now, i want to generate a List where for example a certain role can view the values for ALL users. Therefore i can't use the Session Inject anymore, because the StatisticController now needs to be generated for multiple Users.

Having regular Classes this would not be a big problem - add the userEntity to the constructor. What is the "best practice" to solve this in JSF?

If i modify the StatisticController to something like this:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public StatisticController{

    public void init(User user){
       //load stats for user;
    }
}
```

i would need to call `init(user)` manually of course. How can this be achieved from within a Iteration in the XHTML file?

I could refactor it so the valueLoading happens in the actual getter method, and iterate like this:

```
<ui:repeat var="user" value="#{userDataService.getAllUsers()}">
    <h:outputText value="statisticController.lastLoginDate(user)" />        
    ...
</ui:repeat>
```

But then i would need to load "every" value seperate, which is bad.

So a way like this would be "better":

```
<ui:repeat var="user" value="#{userDataService.getAllUsers()}">
    statisticController.init(user);
    <h:outputText value="statisticController.lastLoginDate()" />        
    ...
</ui:repeat>
```

However this doesnt look very comfortable either. Further more doing things like this, will move nearly "all" Backend Stuff into the Render Response Phase, which is feeling wrong.

Any Ideas / Tipps how to solve this in a way that's not feeling "like a workaround"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new model wrapping those models.

```
public class UserStatistics {

    private User user;
    private Statistics statistics;

    // ...
}
```

So that you can just use e.g.

```
public class UserStatisticsBacking {

    private List<UserStatistics> list;

    @EJB
    private UserService userService;

    @EJB
    private StatisticsService statisticsService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        list = new ArrayList<UserStatistics>();

        for (User user : userService.list()) {
            list.add(new UserStatistics(user, statisticsService.get(user)));
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

*(better would be to perform it in a new `UserStatisticsService` though)*

with

```
<ui:repeat value="#{userStatisticsBacking.list}" var="userStatistics">
    <h:outputText value="#{userStatistics.user.name}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{userStatistics.statistics.lastLoginDate}" />
    ...
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Thank you, that made it way clearer. Im always mixing the Model and the Service, which then does not fit into the application very well :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using a wrapped model proposed by BalusC is to store two separate lists with model data. With this approach you don't need to introduce modifications.

Following this route you'll be iterating over one list with `<ui:repeat>` and, ensuring equality of sizes of both lists, get second list element by index, which in turn is available via `varStatus` attribute that exports the iteration status variable.

```
<ui:param name="stats" value="#{bean.stats}/>
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.users}" var="user" varStatus="status">
    <h:outputText value="#{user}/>
    <h:outputText value="#{stats[status.index]}/>
</ui:include>
```

Population of lists may be done beforehand in `PostConstruct` method:

```
private List<User> users;
private List<Statistic> stats;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    users = userService.list();
    stats = statService.list();
}
```

Comment: That seems to loosely coupled. Especially when sorting the stats, i somehow would need to maintain the connection to the user.